# Understanding Linux top CPU utilisation output

Tags: linux, performance

I'm using an single core small ARM processor running under Debian and have problems understanding the CPU utilisation output of top, see:

```
top - 15:31:54 up 30 days, 23:00,  2 users,  load average: 0.90, 0.89, 0.87
Tasks:  44 total,   1 running,  43 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 65.0%us, 20.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 14.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:     61540k total,    40056k used,    21484k free,        0k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    22260k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                    
26028 root      20   0  2536 1124  912 R  1.9  1.8   0:00.30 top                                                                                        
31231 root      19  -1 45260  964  556 S  1.9  1.6   1206:15 owserver                                                                                   
    3 root      15  -5     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:08.68 ksoftirqd/0                                                                                
  694 root      20   0 28640  840  412 S  0.3  1.4 468:26.74 rsyslogd
```

The column %CPU is very low over all processes, in this example it is all together 4,4% (all other process below had been on 0%)
But the allover CPU on line 3 shows 65%us and 20%sy, so for both a very high value - and by the way, this is how the system feels: very slow :-(
The system is almost always in this condition: very low CPU for all processes, but high user+system CPU.
Can anybody explain why there is such a high inconsistence within the top tool output?
And what tool can I use to better find out what causes the high user+system CPU utilization - top seems to be useless here.

**update**: meanwhile I've found this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319894/cpu-column-and-load-in-top), which discusses a similiar question, but I can't verify what is written there:

- The command *uptime* shows the average CPU utilization per 1/5/15 minutes
- This is close to what the first line of *top* outputs as sum of %us+%sy. But this is changing much more, maybe it is an average per 10s?
- Even if looking longer time on the top output, the sum of %us+%sy is always several times higher than the summary of all %CPU

Thanks
   Achim

Answer (score 7):

You should read the `manpage` of `top` to understand its output more astutely. From the manpage:

> %CPU  --  CPU usage

The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update, expressed as a percentage of total CPU time. The default screen update time is 3 seconds, which can be changed with `#top -d ss.tt`. To measure commulative CPU usage, run `top -S`.

> -S : Cumulative time mode toggle

Starts top with the last remembered 'S' state reversed.  When 'Cumulative mode' is On, each process is listed with the cpu time that it and its  dead  children  have  used.

The CPU states are shown in the Summary Area. They are always shown as a percentage and are for the time between now and the last refresh.

```
    us  --  User CPU time
      The time the CPU has spent running users' processes that are not niced.

    sy  --  System CPU time
      The time the CPU has spent running the kernel and its processes.

    ni  --  Nice CPU time
      The time the CPU has spent running users' proccess that have been niced.

    wa  --  iowait
      Amount of time the CPU has been waiting for I/O to complete.

    hi  --  Hardware IRQ
      The amount of time the CPU has been servicing hardware interrupts.

    si  --  Software Interrupts
      The amount of time the CPU has been servicing software interrupts.

    st  --  Steal Time
      The amount of CPU 'stolen' from this virtual machine by the hypervisor for other tasks (such as running another virtual machine).
```

Under normal circumstances %us+%sy should always be higher.